# getPacketManager().resolveActivity(...) - Fails only with system applications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

When i call the resolveActivity() function with system packageNames i receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getHost()' on a null object reference
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.resolveIntent(IPackageManager.java:2513)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivityAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:545)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivity(ApplicationPackageManager.java:539)
        at com.github.aayvazyan.polyse.util.APKInfo.getResolveInfo(APKInfo.java:87)
```

This exception is reproduceable via:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.calendar");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    ResolveInfo result = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0);
```

I use SDK 21 and Build Tools "21.1.1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this problem I initialized Intent with the following instead of the empty constructor:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
```